# Eloquent ORM - Models Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, orm, eloquent, octobercms

I am fairly new to **OctoberCMS / Lavarel ORM** and I am kind of stuck implementing models relationship. I have two database tables / Models where one represents general information about programs `A, B, C` and the second general information about the different levels related to these programs..

**Objective** : I would like to retrieve the info for a certain program `X` **+** retrieve all info for the program levels associated with it.

### Models

**Model 1 - Table Schema**

```
    Schema::create('pgs_programs', function($table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->char('prog_code', 10); // Unique ID/SKU
        $table->string("prog_slug" )->nullable();
        $table->string("prog_title")->nullable();
        $table->text("prog_intro_title")->nullable();
        $table->text("prog_intro")->nullable();
        $table->text("prog_top_img" )->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Model 2 - Table Schema**

```
    Schema::create('pgs_program_levels', function($table)
{
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->char('prog_code', 10); // Related to Parent Program ID/SKU
    $table->string('level_title')->nullable();
    $table->enum('prog_level', array(4,5,6,7))->nullable();
    $table->text('prog_duration')->nullable();
    $table->text("prog_desc")->nullable();
    $table->text("prog_assesments" )->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

### Component

```
namespace PGS\Program\Components;
use Cms\Classes\ComponentBase;
use PGS\Program\Models\Program;  // Model 1
use PGS\Program\Models\ProgramLevels; // Model 2

  public function onRun(){

    $Programmes = Program::all();
    $X = $this->param('programme');
    $Y = $this->param('disciplines');
    $slug = $X."/".$Y ;
    $arr = array();

       foreach($Programmes as $k){
                $arr[]= $k['prog_slug'];
            }
      if(in_array($slug, $arr) ){
          // here query both models
          // this query gets General info from table1
          $progInfo = Program::where('prog_slug', '=', $slug)->first(); 
                } else {
                    return $this->controller->run('404');
                }
}
```

I'd like to understand / use the `array Relations` so I can do the following in one query. I know I can do multiple queries :

Query 1:

```
 $progInfo = Program::where('prog_slug', '=', $slug)->first();
```

then Query 2:

```
 $progLvlsInfo = ProgramLevels::where('prog_code', '=', $progInfo['prog_code'])->get();
 // returns array of all program levels
```

I came accross this post on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860151/querying-many-to-one-to-relation-in-october-cms-as-a-join) that treats this same issue. I tried adding the `$belongTo` in the Program Model and vice versa but had no success..

```
 public $belongsTo = [
        'program' =>       ['PGS\Program\Models\ProgramLevels',
            'foreignKey' => 'prog_code']
    ];
```

Should I stick to doing two queries as above, or use Join statements or use the relations provided in the model..

```
public $hasOne = [];
public $hasMany = [];
public $belongsTo = [];
public $belongsToMany = [];
public $morphTo = [];
public $morphOne = [];
public $morphMany = [];
public $attachOne = [];
public $attachMany = [];
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As your app grows in complexity you are going to want to figure out relationships... they will make your life so much more sane.

Comment: @LuckyBurger I know!! :) I just don't seem to understand them yet.. I thought i'd rather try to pick up good habits from the start. I am not sure if the above is considered bad logic/code..

Comment: are you having trouble figuring out the syntax ? Do you need an example or 2?

Comment: mmm more about how to create the relation between Model A and Model B, so when I query Model A I will get also relevant records from Model B, in this case if I query a Program get all related levels (disciplines ) where each discipline / record ( prog_code) represent a unique Key for the parent Program.. :/ as i mentioned above I am able to do this with 2 queries, so I was wondering if using $belongTo will substitute the need of query 2 ? or the use of relations is for different purposes and I should stick to this method for now..

Comment: belongsTo isnt the only relation... you probably want to figure out hasOne, hasMany, hasManyThrough ...

Answer (score 0):

Define Class UserAccount

Define Class Games

A UserAccount can have more than 1 game.

```
//UserAccount 
function games() {
    return $this->hasMany('Games', 'user_id');
}

UserAccount::find(1)->games();
```

Reference:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations